# I have a 2000 Jetta 1.8t. can I use a computer from a 2018 Jetta 1.8 t? And if so are the tunes different?

Tags: vw, electronic-control-module, jetta, part-interchange

I have a 2000 Volkswagen Jetta 1.8T can I use a computer out of a 2018 Jetta same motor if so what are the advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If my sources are right, the only electronic control modules you might be able to use are ones for 2000 or 2001 Jetta (PN: 06A 906 018 ET). It appears VW used the same one for the different engines (VR6, 2.8L, 2.0L, and even the 1.9 diesel). These would all have different maps in them, so would have to be tuned for your specific vehicle. **The 2018 will not work (PN: 04E 907 309 AP).**